# Why the shadow (due to elevation) below the tabs disappearing when using CollapsingToolbarLayout? Please see details

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm developing a **material design** app.

I'm using a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

**The problem is that the shadow (due to elevation) which appears below `Tabs' is no more there**.

Please consider the following images:

**Screenshot of screen before using `CollapsingToolbarLayout` (see - there is shadow below the tabs here)**:

[image]

**Screenshot of screen after using `CollapsingToolbarLayout` (see - no shadow below the tabs here)**:

[image]

**Here's `activity_main.xml` file's code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="App name"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_gravity="start|center" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/fragment_main"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <!--<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

What could be wrong here?

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` to `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"`.

This will do the job.